# Do I have to wait for frozen steak to defrost?

Tags: steak, frozen

If I have several frozen steaks I wish to cook (and eat) is there some easier way to do so than by just waiting for them to defrost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cook steaks from frozen, it is just a matter of adjusting cooking times.

They will take longer to cook. But you have saved several hours in defrost time.

I take my frozen steaks and sear on both sides, then finish them off in the oven for about 16 mins depending on cut, or with a thicker cut for about 18 to 20 mins.

America's Test Kitchen has experimented with this idea and says that the steaks taste better cooked from frozen ([see here on youtube](http://youtu.be/uLWsEg1LmaE)).

I have to watch the temperature otherwise the steak might get a little tough, but I always preheat the oven. For me, 180 °C.

Comment: Great, great video! +1 Excellent advice on the freezing technique, watch the video all the way through, folks.

Comment: Great video indeed. A few things I noted. 1. They have _perfect_ cuts of beef. 2. They are measuring the inner temperature in the oven, accounting for resting. This is not your average dinner procedure.

Comment: That surprises me; i'll have to watch that when I'm at home.  The big risk of cooking from frozen, if I recall correctly, is that due to the temperature differential they'll overcook on the outside before the inside is correctly cooked more so than usual - this is why it is recommended to bring your steaks out of the fridge for half an hour or so to let them come up closer to room temperature (though I've always thought that was a bit silly, since it's only 25% of the temperature difference at best).

Comment: I just followed the instructions on the video (including freezing technique) for an inch thick sirloin. At 18 minutes (+7 minutes to rest), the steak was *perfect* for me, which would be a bit rare for most. I used a 275F (135C) oven. I can now get the family pack of steaks and actually use them up! YAY!